# Should i use multi bloc provider with multi bloc Listener?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

In flutter bloc if i need to use multi bloc listener to make bloc to bloc communitication , should i use multi bloc provider?

Comment: mulTiBlocProvider is just a shortcut, see its code to understand it

Comment: please write your question again @Winter

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MultiBlocProvider` to pass one `bloc` into another `bloc` like this:

```dart
MultiBlocProvider(
  providers: [
    BlocProvider<FirstBloc>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => FirstBloc(),
    ),
    BlocProvider<SecondBloc>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => SecondBloc(
        firstBloc: BlocProvider.of<FirstBloc>(context),
        ...
      ),
    ),
  ],
  child: App(),
);
```